# PHP change from 5.4 to 5.6

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been given a task that I managed to resolve however my web host has moved php from 5.4 to 5.6 and now in the process of changing mysql to mysqli,  however I have part that just out and out refuses to work under mysqli however does work under mysql. Im quite new to PHP and didnt write the original code,  just tried everything else to work out whats going wrong.

I have set the connector up correctly in the wp-config file and put an echo out to check connectivity.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: ajax.php
*/
?>
<?php

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-config.php");


$action = $_REQUEST['action'];

switch($action)
{
    case 'get_all_model_for_make':
{
    get_all_model_for_make();
    break;
}
case 'get_all_vehicle_group_for_make_and_model':
{
    get_all_vehicle_group_for_make_and_model();
    break;
}
}


function get_all_model_for_make()
{

$make_id = $_REQUEST['make_id'];
?>
<select name="bhr_model" id="bhr_model" class="option_class" onChange="return get_all_vehicle_group_for_make_and_model('<?php echo $make_id; ?>',this.value);">
    <option value="">-Select BHR Model-</option>
    <?php
    $sel_bhr_model = "SELECT DISTINCT (bm.bhr_model_id) AS bhr_model_id, bm.bhr_model_name FROM bhr_model bm LEFT JOIN basic_hire_rate bhr ON bm.bhr_model_id = bhr.bhr_model WHERE bhr.bhr_make = '".$make_id."' ORDER BY bm.bhr_model_name";
    $exe_bhr_model = @mysql_query($sel_bhr_model);
    while($res_bhr_model = @mysql_fetch_array($exe_bhr_model))

    {
        echo '<option value="'.$res_bhr_model['bhr_model_id'].'">'.$res_bhr_model['bhr_model_name'].'</option>';
    }
    mysqli_close($conn)
    ?>
    </select>
    <?php
 }


function get_all_vehicle_group_for_make_and_model()
{
$make_id = $_REQUEST['make_id'];
$model_id = $_REQUEST['model_id'];
?>
<select name="bhr_gta_vehicle_group" id="bhr_gta_vehicle_group" class="option_class">
    <option value="">-Select BHR Vehicle Group-</option>
    <?php
    $sel_vg = "SELECT DISTINCT(vg.bhr_gta_vehicle_group_id) AS bhr_gta_vehicle_group_id, vg.bhr_gta_vehicle_group_name FROM bhr_gta_vehicle_group vg LEFT JOIN basic_hire_rate bhr ON vg.bhr_gta_vehicle_group_id = bhr.bhr_gta_vehicle_group WHERE bhr.bhr_make = '".$make_id."'  AND bhr.bhr_model = '".$model_id."' ORDER BY vg.bhr_gta_vehicle_group_name";
    $exe_vg = mysql_query($sel_vg);
    while($res_vg = mysql_fetch_array($exe_vg))
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$res_vg['bhr_gta_vehicle_group_id'].'">'.$res_vg['bhr_gta_vehicle_group_name'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
?>
```

This code currently works in 5.4 but cant migrate to 5.6 unless I change to mysqli but when i change to mysqli it fails in 5.4 also.

i,e

```
$exe_bhr_model = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_bhr_model);
while($res_bhr_model = mysqli_fetch_array($exe_bhr_model))
```

please help as I have been fighting this every step of the way.

Comment: `mysql_*` should work fine under php 5.6, it has been removed from php 7. I would definitely recommend switching to PDO or mysqli and take advantage of prepared statement, but you don't need it to get it to work. What is the problem that you have exactly?

Comment: Error messages please.

Comment: Since your'e using wordpress I suggest you switch to using the wordpress database access methods. Check out [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). This way you delegate the version compatibilities to wordpress and don't have to worry about it yourself

Comment: "it fails" isn't an error message or problem statement. Please provide sufficient details, such as exact errors or descriptions of unexpected behaviour, to allow people to diagnose the problem.

Comment: "when i change to mysqli it fails in 5.4 also.". So in fact you have already realised this isn't about the PHP version at all. In which case, why did you make it the title of the question? Presumably it's something to do with mysqli in reality.

Comment: Please understand that if you do not find a solution to this, at least do something with those queries. You are WIDE open for attacks.

Comment: By the way, apart from the sql injection this looks like a simple variable scope problem. You need to pass the connection to your functions.

Comment: im really sorry for coming across as an idiot,  ive asked it to display errors,  and it doesn't come up with any.  I put the connection into the config file so it does come up as connected,  the only difference I can see between the PHP5.4 and PHP 5.6 is the mysql to mysqli change which is what i've been trying to do. 
Unexpectected behavour

PHP 5.4 I get a drop down box with the DB for Make, Model
PHP 5.6 I get an empty drop down box with no errors reported

PHP 5.4 doesnt care about most of the mysqli statements apart from the code i posted. :(

Comment: Thanks Jeroen ,  you pointed me in the right direction,  mysqli needs to be global to be accessed in a function ergo it was falling over.